# Google Maps Marker disappears during setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a setInterval() every second to go through a bunch of infowindows and update the timer associated with each.

On initial map load, I generate a bunch of markers, each with a different countdown counter in each infowindow.

Currently, I'm getting feedback that it works for some users , but it doesn't for others (I know some, I don't know if all, are in a different timezone than me) and I can't figure out why.

Below should be a minimized and verifiable working code. Locations is just a json encoded array of table rows returned by a PHP executing SQL query.

```
<script>
  var infowindows = [];
  var placeMarkers = [];
  var currentMarker = null;
  var markers = [];
  var durations = [];
  var locations = eval('<?php echo $info ?>');
  var map = null;
  var globalPosition = {
      lat: 41.8781,
      lng: -87.6298
  }


  function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: globalPosition,
      zoom: 17
    });

    getCurrentLocation();
    setInfo(map, locations); 
  }


  function closeAllInfoWindow(){
    for (var i=0; i < infowindows.length; i++) {
      infowindows[i].close();
    }
  }


  function getCurrentLocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        globalPosition = pos;
        map.setCenter(pos);

        if (currentMarker){
          currentMarker.setMap(null);
        }

        setCurrentMarker(map);

      }, function() {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, globalPosition);
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, globalPosition);

    }
  }
  function setCurrentMarker(map){
    if (currentMarker){
      currentMarker.setMap(null);
    }
    currentMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      icon: {
        url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Pokeball.PNG",
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 20),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      },
      title: "Current Location",
      position: globalPosition
    });
  }

  function removeEverything(map, locations){
    for (var i = 0 ; i < markers.length; i++){
      markers[i].setMap(null);
      infowindows[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
  function setInfo(map, locations){
      removeEverything(map, locations); // remove everything and reload with new locations in additional to the old ones
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var updatedTime = new Date(locations[i]['updatedDate'].replace(/-/g,"/"));
      var duration = parseInt(locations[i]['spawnDuration']);

      durations[i] = Math.floor((updatedTime.getTime() - Date.now())/1000) + duration;
      var durationMinutes = Math.floor(durations[i] / 60);
      var durationSeconds = durations[i] - durationMinutes * 60;

      var hour = locations[i]['hour'];
      var minute = (locations[i]['minute'] < 10 ? '0' + locations[i]['minute'] : locations[i]['minute']);
      var AMPM = (hour>= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM');
      if (hour > 12){
        hour -= 12;
      }

      markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['latitude'], locations[i]['longitude']),
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -50)
      });

      infowindows[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        maxWidth: 180,
        maxHeight: 100,
        disableAutoPan: true,
        content: 
        'Time Left: ' + '<b>' + durationMinutes + ' min ' + durationSeconds  + ' seconds' + '</b>' + '</br>'

      });      
    }
  }
  // reload markers and infowindows every second
  setInterval(function(){
    for (var i=0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var hour = locations[i]['hour'];
      var minute = (locations[i]['minute'] < 10 ? '0' + locations[i]['minute'] : locations[i]['minute']);
      var AMPM = (hour>= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM');
      if (hour > 12){
        hour -= 12;
      }
      durations[i]--;
      if (durations[i] <= 0){
        infowindows[i].close();
        markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      var durationMinutes = Math.floor(durations[i] / 60);
      var durationSeconds = durations[i] - durationMinutes * 60;
      infowindows[i].setContent(
            'Time Left: ' + '<b>' + durationMinutes + ' min ' + durationSeconds  + ' seconds' + '</b>' + '</br>');

    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MyAPIKey]&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

The map usually only has 100 - 1000 markers.

Comment: I don't see anyway the posted code could work (`markers.setMap(null)` should cause an error).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (or at least shows your working code that fails for some people).

Comment: @geocodezip, can I provide the website link instead? Or only code? I can provide the full code  or parts of it in a few hours when I get home, aka access to the code source.  :(

Comment: The SO policy is to ask for a [mcve] in the question itself, a website will get fixed and no longer exhibit the issue, which won't be useful to future readers.

Comment: @geocodezip, gotcha, I will try to include that as soon as I get home in a few hours :)

Comment: @geocodezip, added an minimized version of the code without all the event listeners since those are irrelevant. Is this in the correct format?

Comment: Can you provide some test values for the locations array?  This line `var locations = eval('<?php echo $info ?>');` doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

As geocodezip mentioned, your code as it is now is not runnable, and a minimal *testable* case will help. (BTW I assume things like `timer` vs. `timers` are just typos.)

In the meantime, I see a race condition in the code you posted which could explain some inconsistent results. There is a `setInfo()` function that is called "on page load". Outside this function is a `setInterval()` with a one-second interval.

Let me assume you are calling `setInfo()` in an `onload` event listener or the like. This listener will not be called until all the page's resources (images and everything) are loaded.

But note that your initial `setInterval()` call happens *before* this, when the page is initially loading. The call to `setInterval()` is made before the body of `setInfo()` is run.

When you're testing your page, you probably either have all of its resources already cached, or you're on a fast connection and they load quickly - in less than a second. So `setInfo()` gets called before the first `setInterval()` callback is triggered.

But that's just sheer luck. What happens on a slow connection that takes more than one second to load everything?

The first `setInterval()` callback happens at the one second mark, but since the entire page is not loaded yet, `setInfo()` hasn't been called. Oops.

This is easy to fix: instead of calling `setInterval()` outside the `setInfo()` function, move that call *inside* `setInfo()` as the last thing it does.

That will insure that the first interval callback won't be triggered until after `setInfo()` has done its job.

This may not be the specific problem you ran into - but if it isn't, it is a problem that will show up sooner or later.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you mean. But even if the first `setInterval()` happened before `setInfo()`. When `setInfo()` loads in, `setInterval()` should work fine, shouldn't it? If the first `setInterval()` runs before `setInfo()`, it pretty much won't do anything, but it won't affect `setInfo()` at all right? So on the map, once `setInfo` is ran, the map should still be populated?Maybe that's not it works.